# Listing all words containing more than 1 capitalized letter

Tags: bash

I want to search for all of the acronyms placed within a document so I can correct their formatting. I think I can assume that all acronyms are words containing at least 2 capital letters in them (e.g.: "EU"), as I've never seen a one-word acronym or acronym only containing 1 capital letter, but sometimes they have a small "o" for "of" in them or another small letter. How can I print out a list showing all of the possible matches once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work for you:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/\n/g' $your_file  | sort -u | egrep '[[:upper:]].*[[:upper:]]'
```

Translation:

- Replace all runs of whitespace in `$your_file` with newlines.  This will put each word on its own line.
- Sort the file and remove duplicates.
- Find all lines that contain two uppercase letters separated by zero or more characters.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' <input.txt | sed '/\<[[:upper:]]\{2,\}\>/!d' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 2):

The `-o` option of grep can help you:

```
grep -o '\b[[:alpha:]]*[[:upper:]][[:alpha:]]*[[:upper:]][[:alpha:]]*'
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost only Bash:

```
for word in  $(cat file.txt) ; do
  if [[ $word =~ [[:upper:]].*[[:upper:]] ]] ; then # at least 2 capital letters
    echo "${word//[^[:alpha:]]/}"                   # remove non-alphabetic characters
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `perl`.

**Example**:

Content of *infile*:

```
One T
Two T
THREE 
Four
Five SIX
```

Running the `perl` command:

```
perl -ne 'printf qq[%s\n], $1 while /\b([[:upper:]]{2,})\b/g' infile
```

Result:

```
THREE
SIX
```

Comment: Will this print a line that contains `ToE` (as in "Theory of Everything")?

Comment: Not mine, but there are other answers which will do.